# How can I ensure that Org-Mode is Up-To-Date in init.el?

Tags: org-mode, package

I want my `init.el` file to get the latest version of `org` from orgmode.org before loading my `pretty-init.org`.

My init.el:

```
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("org" . "http://orgmode.org/elpa/"))
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives
               '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)

(when (boundp 'package-pinned-packages)
  (setq package-pinned-packages
        '((org . "org"))))

;; I don't want the version hardcoded here, but without it
;; package-installed-p will find the built-in org package
(unless (package-installed-p 'org '20151005)
  (package-install 'org))
```

When I run this I get the error `(wrong-type-argument arrayp org)` on the call `(package-install 'org)`.

I think it has something to do with the existence of the built-in `org` package because if I run `(package-install 'nlinum)` when `nlinum` is installed already, I get the same error.

I'm running the latest build of [emacsbinw64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/) and I can install the newest `org` package if I use `M-x list-packages` (though it doesn't work through `M-x package-install` because it doesn't show up in the completion list).

Comment: This is interesting; even running `list-packages` and pressing `U` doesn't mark org for upgrade. Also weirdly, 'org isn't in `package-alist`.

Comment: A few years ago, I went out of my way to make sure org-mode is never updated (even with new installations of Emacs) because I have a working setup already.  If something is working well, it's not always a good idea to update.

Comment: @lawlist Yeah, I might just have to stick to manually installing `org`. I'm not installing the latest version just to have the latest, I actually need it because org-src-fontify-natively is failing on the built-in version.